# Git submodules not pulling

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repo as my master project. It has some sub-modules added to it.

It look like:

```
~/super_project/                <- main git repo
~/super_project/plugins/admin   <- sub-module
~/super_project/plugins/editor  <- sub-module
```

All that's fine, its committed and working.
But when I push the super project to origin/master, and then clone it down to another machine, no sub-modules get pulled.

Ive tried `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` and `git submodule update --init`, they all have no effect.

Comment: When you commit and push in your submodules, do you also commit and push your main parent repo? Also, what exact Git version are you using?

Comment: for `git submodule` to work you need a `.gitmodules` file in your superproject. You have that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you didn't actually pushed your submodules on your master project. Just push them.

If you clone a repository which should contain submodules but there is no `.gitmodules` at the root level it means that the remote server do not have them registered.

First ensure that the submodules are pushed to the server. You need to add the submodules to the parent project (just cloning or creating a repo inside another repo isn't enough).